This is a multi-part message in MIME format
     public function danger()
  {
    // 1
        $uploaddir = 'assets/danger_images/';
        $file1 = $_FILES['img1']['name'];
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$file1;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img1']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] = 'success';       
            $dataDB['filename'] = $file1;
        }
          else 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] =  'failure';       
        }
    // 2
        $uploaddir = 'assets/danger_images/';
        $file2 = $_FILES['img2']['name'];
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$file2;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img2']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] = 'success';       
            $dataDB['filename'] = $file2;
        }
          else 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] =  'failure';       
        }
    // 3
        $uploaddir = 'assets/danger_images/';
        $file3 = $_FILES['img3']['name'];
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$file3;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img3']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] = 'success';       
            $dataDB['filename'] = $file3;
        }
          else 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] =  'failure';       
        }
    // 4
        $uploaddir = 'assets/danger_images/';
        $file4 = $_FILES['img4']['name'];
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$file4;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img4']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] = 'success';       
            $dataDB['filename'] = $file4;
        }
          else 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] =  'failure';       
        }
    // 5
        $uploaddir = 'assets/danger_images/';
        $file5 = $_FILES['img5']['name'];
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$file5;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img5']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] = 'success';       
            $dataDB['filename'] = $file5;
        }
          else 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] =  'failure';       
        }
    // Audio 
        $uploaddir = 'assets/danger_images/';
        $file6 = $_FILES['audio']['name'];
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$file6;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] = 'success';       
            $dataDB['filename'] = $file6;
        }
          else 
        {
            $dataDB['status'] =  'failure';       
        }

      $danger_data = array(
        'img1' => $file1,
        'img2' => $file2,
        'img3' => $file3,
        'img4' => $file4,
        'img5' => $file5,
        'audio' => $file6,
        'post_lat' => $this->input->post('post_lat'),
        'post_lng' => $this->input->post('post_lng'),
        'post_created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'user_id'  => $this->input->post('user_id')
      );

      $user_id  = $this->input->post('user_id');
      $result = $this->Api_model->chk_user_blok($user_id);
      if($result == 'block')
      {
        $data['error'] = true;
        $data['msg']   = 'Your account was blocked by admin';
        echo json_encode($data);
      }
      else
      {
        $this->db->insert('danger',$danger_data);
        $id =  $this->db->insert_id();
        $r = $this->Api_model->get_danger_record($id);
        $address = $this->getaddress($r->post_lat,$r->post_lng);
        if(empty($address))
        {
          $address = "Danger+Location";
        }
        $authemail = $r->authemail;
        $self = $r->useremail;

        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('support@crighter.com', 'Crighter');
        
        //$this->email->to($authemail,$self);       
        $list = array($authemail, $self);
        $this->email->to($list);            
        
        $this->email->subject('Danger');
        $this->email->message($r->userfullname." is in danger.You were declared as an authorised person.\n There current latitude & longitude are ".$r->post_lat.','.$r->post_lng.'.'."\nhttp://maps.google.com/maps?q=".$r->post_lat.','.$r->post_lng.'+('.$address.')&z=14&ll='.$r->post_lat.','.$r->post_lng);
        $this->email->attach(base_url().'assets/danger_images/'.$r->img1);
        $this->email->attach(base_url().'assets/danger_images/'.$r->img2);
        $this->email->attach(base_url().'assets/danger_images/'.$r->img3);
        $this->email->attach(base_url().'assets/danger_images/'.$r->img4);
        $this->email->attach(base_url().'assets/danger_images/'.$r->img5);
        $this->email->attach(base_url().'assets/danger_images/'.$r->audio);

        if($this->email->send())
        {
          $data['error'] = false;
          $data['msg']   = 'Post Submited';
          echo json_encode($data);
        }
        else
        {
          $data['error'] = True;
          $data['msg']   = 'Cant Submited';
          echo json_encode($data);
        }
        
        

        
      }
  }

I am using this function using php mailer for sending all these details 5 images + audio + location on server side its capturing all the details but on email its showing this error kindly recommend the solution for this.
Email :
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.
--B_ATC_66573b5877b1e
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
abc is in danger.You were declared as an authorised person.
There current latitude & longitude are
24.876905035849703,67.06579372417758.
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=24.876905035849703,67.06579372417758+(Danger+Location)&z=14&ll=24.876905035849703,67.06579372417758

This string was removed from PHPMailer some time ago, suggesting that you're running an old version, so get the latest.

So I just need to update the php mailer?

I can't tell what version you're running, but it's very old and there have been many updates and bug fixes since then, so it's very likely to fix your issue. This should be the first thing you do with any external package, and composer will help you do that.

Don’t know how to do that any help or article will be appreciated

Here's how to install PHPMailer manually, and here's how to use composer.
